# Facebook Comment Box Dynamic Pages XID

Tags: facebook-comments

I have integrated FB comment box here:
http://slotenis.si/tenis-igrisce.asp

But it is now working. The thing is, that I show tennis courts by ID, for example:

```
http://slotenis.si/tenis-igrisce.asp?lid=1
http://slotenis.si/tenis-igrisce.asp?lid=2
http://slotenis.si/tenis-igrisce.asp?lid=3
etc.
```

I retreive lid from the database in classic ASP variable LocationID.

For this reason, I have integrated the FB comment box with the followin code:

```
div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments xid="<%=LocationID%>" href="http://www.slotenis.si/tenis-igrisce.asp" num_posts="10" width="630"></fb:comments>
```

When I try to post a comment, it takes some time, but nothing happens.

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had an error in domain name, tennis.si instead of tenis.si. What a stupid mistake.